# Finding $(ab)^{-2}$ and $(a^{-1})(b^{-1})$ for $a=(236)(57), b=(147).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

I have a problem with following example:

> $a = (236)(57), b = (147)$
>
> I need to find
>
> 1. $(ab)^{-2}$
> 2. $(a^{-1})(b^{-1})$

How to solve it? I know, how to find $(ab)^{-1}$:

$$((236)(1475))^{-1} = (263)(1574)$$

But how can I multiply $(263)(1574)(263)(1574)$ in order to get $(ab)^{-2}$?

Comment: if you have $(ab)^{-1}$, then $(ab)^{-2}$ is the product you posted, notice that, since $(263)$ and $(1574)$ are have different values, they commute, so $(ab)^{-2}=(263)(1574)(263)(1574)=(263)^2(1574)^2=(236)(17)(45)$

Comment: Since $(263)$ and $(1574)$ commute, it is just $(263)^2(1574)^2=(236)(17)(45)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the basic cycle formations are disjoint you have
$$
(263)(1574)(263)(1574) = (263)(263)(1574)(1574)
$$
which amounts to shifting around the same cycle twice, i.e. $(1574)^2 = (17)(54)$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think, that I already understand the problem. I´ve just a question. In order to get (17)(54) I have to move firstly from 1->5->7(17) and secondly from 5->7->4(54)?

Comment: @embe99 the idea is you will move along $(1574)$ twice, so you map $1 \to 5 \to 7$, $5 \to 7 \to 1$ and the other way, ending up with two $2$-cycles, which won't be the case in $(263)$, for example.

Comment: Yes, I´ve got it! Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 3):

First do $$(263)(1574)(263)(1574)=(263)^2(1574)^2=(236)(17)(45)$$

Then the inverse is $$(263)(17)(45)$$